# Looking through email inbox and setting an array to contents of file only if file type is csv using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, csv, keyword, php-7

Hey so what id like to do is have my script check to see if the attachment of an email has the extensione csv, if yes add it's contents to an array of arrays and move to the next email then when all the emails have been looked at save the array of arrays to separate files. What im struggling with is the part where i checks what file type the attachment is and only proceeds if the file type is csv, i cant seem to find any reverences to the the keywords i should be doing online. If anyone could point me in the right direction or adapt my code to do the check it would be greatly appreciated 
So heres my code so far and thanks for any help you can give me in advance:

```
<?php include (application.php);
    /* connect to gmail with your credentials */
    $mailbox = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX'; /* This bit tells the script where to look and what folder to look for */
    $email_server_username = 'YOUR_email_server_username'; /* The email servers username */
    $email_server_username_server_password = 'YOUR_email_server_username_server_password'; /* The password asspciated with the above username */
    /* connect to sql db with your credentials */
    $username = "";
    $password = "";
    $databasename = "testdb"; /*Set testdb to the database name*/
    $databasename = new mysqli("localhost", $username, $password, $databasename) or die("Connection to server failed, please check email_server_username, password and database name"); /*local host should be the ip of the server unless this script is run locally*/
    set_time_limit(3000);

    /* try to connect to server*/
    $inbox = imap_open($mailbox,$email_server_username,$email_server_username_server_password) or die('Failed to connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());
    $email_server_usernames = imap_search($inbox, 'FROM "abc@gmail.com"');
    /* if any email_server_usernames are found, the script will iterate through each of them */
    if($email_server_usernames) {
        $count = 1;
        /* sorts by newest first */
        rsort($email_server_usernames);
        /* for every value in email_server_username... */
        foreach($email_server_usernames as $email_server_username_number){
            /* get information specific to this email */
            $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_server_username_number,0);
            $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_server_username_number,2);
            /* get mail structure */
            $structure = imap_fetchstructure($inbox, $email_server_username_number);
            $attachments = array();
            /* if any attachments found... */
            if(isset($structure->parts) && count($structure->parts)){
                for($i = 0; $i < count($structure->parts); $i++){
                    $attachments[$i] = array(
                        'is_attachment' => false,
                        'filename' => '',
                        'name' => '',
                        'attachment' => '',
                    );
                    if($structure->parts[$i]->ifdparameters){
                        foreach($structure->parts[$i]->dparameters as $object){
                            if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'filename')
                            {
                                $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                                $attachments[$i]['filename'] = $object->value;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if($structure->parts[$i]->ifparameters){
                        foreach($structure->parts[$i]->parameters as $object){
                            if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'name'){
                                $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                                $attachments[$i]['name'] = $object->value;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if($attachments[$i]['is_attachment']){
                        $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_server_username_number, $i+1);
                        /* Extracts the email contents into usable text, 3 = BASE64 encoding*/
                        if($structure->parts[$i]->encoding == 3){
                            $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = base64_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
                        }
                        /* 4 = QUOTED-PRINTABLE encoding */
                        elseif($structure->parts[$i]->encoding == 4){
                            $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = quoted_printable_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            /* iterate through each attachment and save it */
            foreach($attachments as $attachment){
                if($attachment['is_attachment'] == 1)
                {
                    $filename = $attachment['name'];
                    if(empty($filename)) $filename = $attachment['filename'];

                    if(empty($filename)) $filename = time() . ".dat";
                    $folder = "attachment";
                    if(!is_dir($folder)){
                         mkdir($folder);
                    }
                    $fp = fopen("./". $folder ."/". $email_server_username_number . "-" . $filename, "w+");
                    fwrite($fp, $attachment['attachment']);
                    fclose($fp);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    /* close the connection to the email_server_username server */
    imap_close($inbox);

    echo "####################Script ran with no errors####################";
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($attachments[$i]["file"]["type"] == "text/csv")
{Result}
```

This will help you.